# Bulk Export pictures from excel cells file using VBA

Tags: vba

I have two columns in excel sheet.

Cells in Column A has image names and Cells in Column B has image.

I am looking for a VBA solution to export images one by one to a folder with given file name in same rows.

Comment: Hi Jetspice, please consider adding to the post anything you have tried and the specific problems you are having as this will make it easier to get support from the community.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have helped you with a very similar question a few days ago.  This is how you import images.

```
Sub InsertPics()
Dim fPath As String, fName As String
Dim r As Range, rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fPath = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\"
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
i = 1

For Each r In rng
    fName = Dir(fPath)
    Do While fName <> ""
        If fName = r.Value Then
            With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fPath & fName)
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                Set px = .ShapeRange
                If .ShapeRange.Width > Rows(i).Columns(2).Width Then .ShapeRange.Width = Columns(2).Width
                    With Cells(i, 2)
                        px.Top = .Top
                        px.Left = .Left
                        .RowHeight = px.Height
                    End With
            End With
        End If
        fName = Dir
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

' Note: you need the file extension, such as ',jpg', or whatever you are using, so you can match on that.

This is how you move images (or any kind of files)

Copy or Move one file

```
For one file you can use the VBA Name and FileCopy function and for entire folders or a lot of files use the other macro example's on this page.

Sub Copy_One_File()
    FileCopy "C:\Users\Ron\SourceFolder\Test.xls", "C:\Users\Ron\DestFolder\Test.xls"
End Sub

Sub Move_Rename_One_File()
'You can change the path and file name
    Name "C:\Users\Ron\SourceFolder\Test.xls" As "C:\Users\Ron\DestFolder\TestNew.xls"
End Sub
```

Copy or move more files or complete folders

```
Note: Read the commented code lines in the code

Sub Copy_Folder()
'This example copy all files and subfolders from FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: If ToPath already exist it will overwrite existing files in this folder
'if ToPath not exist it will be made for you.
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    FromPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Data"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Test"    '<< Change

    'If you want to create a backup of your folder every time you run this macro
    'you can create a unique folder with a Date/Time stamp.
    'ToPath = "C:\Users\Ron\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd h-mm-ss")

    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub


Sub Move_Rename_Folder()
'This example move the folder from FromPath to ToPath.
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    FromPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Data"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Test"    '<< Change
    'Note: It is not possible to use a folder that exist in ToPath

    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = True Then
        MsgBox ToPath & " exist, not possible to move to a existing folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.MoveFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "The folder is moved from " & FromPath & " to " & ToPath

End Sub


Sub Copy_Files_Dates()
'This example copy all files between certain dates from FromPath to ToPath.
'You can also use this to copy the files from the last ? days
'If Fdate >= Date - 30 Then
'Note: If the files in ToPath already exist it will overwrite
'existing files in this folder
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim Fdate As Date
    Dim FileInFromFolder As Object

    FromPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Data"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Test"    '<< Change

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        ToPath = ToPath & "\"
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
        MsgBox ToPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each FileInFromFolder In FSO.getfolder(FromPath).Files
        Fdate = Int(FileInFromFolder.DateLastModified)
        'Copy files from 1-Oct-2006 to 1-Nov-2006
        If Fdate >= DateSerial(2006, 10, 1) And Fdate <= DateSerial(2006, 11, 1) Then
            FileInFromFolder.Copy ToPath
        End If
    Next FileInFromFolder

    MsgBox "You can find the files from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub


Sub Copy_Certain_Files_In_Folder()
'This example copy all Excel files from FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: If the files in ToPath already exist it will overwrite
'existing files in this folder
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileExt As String

    FromPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Data"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Test"    '<< Change

    FileExt = "*.xl*"  '<< Change
    'You can use *.* for all files or *.doc for Word files

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
        MsgBox ToPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub


Sub Move_Certain_Files_To_New_Folder()
'This example move all Excel files from FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: It will create the folder ToPath for you with a date-time stamp
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileExt As String
    Dim FNames As String

    FromPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Data"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Users\Ron\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd h-mm-ss") _
           & " Excel Files" & "\"    '<< Change only the destination folder

    FileExt = "*.xl*"   '<< Change
    'You can use *.* for all files or *.doc for word files

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    FNames = Dir(FromPath & FileExt)
    If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files in " & FromPath
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    FSO.CreateFolder (ToPath)

    FSO.MoveFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```